# What's a sane way to define custom travis job?

Tags: python, docker, travis-ci

Currently travis-ci does not support multiple languages or custom jobs at all. I'm aware that I can install a second language in the `before_install` hook though.

Let me explain my scenario:

I have a Python package which I currently unit test via travis with `language: python` for multiple Python versions. Now I want to add an additional Job which uses docker to build and run a container to build the Python package as debian package.

One option would be to just do it for every Job but that would slow down the test time significantly. Thus, I want to avoid that. 
Another option would be to work with environment variables in set in the build matrix of travis and check an env variable if it's set and if that's so I'd run the docker integration tests.

Both of those options seem rather bad and hacky.

Thus, what's a sane way of adding such a custom job to my travis build matrix?

Comment: I think [caching dependencies](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/) may help.

Comment: @running.t Docker images won't be cached. And the docker run actually takes pretty long too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now solved my needs with the new "in Beta" [Build Stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages). It's not exactly what I wanted but it works for now.

See https://github.com/timofurrer/w1thermsensor/blob/master/.travis.yml for the `.travis.yml` and https://travis-ci.org/timofurrer/w1thermsensor/builds/243322310 for the example build.